# escrow payments

Tags: paypal, escrow

My website's functionality would resemble with VWORKER.COM, ELANCE.COM, ODESK.COM etc. Can some one suggest me any payment gateway (other than paypal, moneybookers, alertpay etc) to handle money transactions So would I be able to receive a payment from project owner and deliver the price of a project to project developer through payment gateway (after deducting my fee). Does any payment gateway (other than paypal, moneybookers, alertpay etc) is able to handle such type of money transactions. If so, kindly inform me about it in details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this also varies for each country. I can suggest PayU for example if it's active on your country. Google Wallet is another option.

Answer (score 3):

You Can also try Best among all [escrow.com.](https://www.escrow.com/)

I provide extensible and extra facility of `payment holding.`
Buyer pays to escrow and un till he got his service or merchandise the payment will be remain on escrow side and when buyer send confirmation of getting merchandise escrow pay to seller.

```
Escrow works like this:

   1.Entity A deposits money into Escrow Account for Entity B.
   2.Entity A and Entity B come to an agreement
   3.The Escrow account is deposited to Entity B.
```

`Payment Holding` on escrow site make it **extra-ordinary**.

Just become it's partner and try to implement it, awesome facility.

I have used it.

Comment: Hi Java Curious, Currently i am developing this payment gateway in my project. I need documentation support, kindly provide me link or documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try Transpact.com - Europe's leading Escrow service.

Their API allows integration with just one line of PHP or ASPX (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Braintree escrow service if merchant is US domiciled. This service is available only in US for now.